# How can I implement a Web barcode scanner in React to work in browser (desktop/mobile)?

Tags: reactjs, barcode, barcode-scanner

I would like to have a camera view, which uses device's camera and detects barcodes' data. How can it be done in a React app?

Not for React Native. It has to work both on desktop and mobile using browser.

Comment: Are you trying to implement it from scratch, or you are searching for a plugin ?  `scandit-sdk-react` should do the work

Answer (score 2):

As long as you use a barcode library implemented in JavaScript, you can make your web apps work on both desktop and mobile.

I've written an article - [How to Build Web Barcode Scanner Using React and Webcam](https://www.dynamsoft.com/codepool/web-barcode-scanner-react-webcam.html) which shows you how to build such an app from scratch using Dynamsoft JavaScript Barcode SDK.

**Dynamsoft JavaScript Barcode SDK** is **commercial software**. If you want to use open-source SDK **for free**, you can use **ZXing** as the substitution.

Here is the source code:

https://github.com/yushulx/zxing-cpp-emscripten